# WPF HierarchicalDataTemplate : Binding from ItemTemplate back to parent

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, hierarchical

Given the following template that I am using with a Telerik RadPanelBar control in order to provide an accordion like view with each bar item showing a header, a number of controls used to gather criteria and then "clear" and "search" buttons...

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="radPanelBarSearchCriteriaItemTemplate"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Criteria, Converter={StaticResource radPanelBarItemContentSingleItemConverter}}">
            <TextBlock Margin="5 4 5 6"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Header}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                    Margin="0 20 0 0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <telerik:RadButton Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ClearCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource dialogClearButtonStyle}" />
                            <telerik:RadButton Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SearchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadPanelBar}}}"
                                               Style="{StaticResource dialogSearchButtonStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The problem I have is that the buttons are binding at the wrong level; the "ClearCommand" and "SearchCommand" are both Properties on the same object as the "Header" referenced by the TextBlock in the template and are not properties of the "Criteria" (which is also a property of the same object).

FYI: the converter used on the ItemsSource of the HierarchicalDataTemplate simply takes a single object and presents it to the template as a list of objects.

Can somebody please help me find the correct way to define the Command binding on the buttons in order to get back to hat parent object and reference the "ClearCommand" and "SearchCommand" correctly. As you can see above, I have been trying various combinations but do not seem to be finding the right one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

I was rightly trying to use RelativeSource AncestorType, but searching for the wrong control. In my case, as I was using a Telerik RadPanelBar, I needed to search for the parent PanelBarPanel control...

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:PanelBarPanel}}
```

This has now allowed me access to the "ClearCommand" and "SearchCommand" properties of the object that also exposes the "Criteria" property.

The way to find this was using the "LiveVisualTree" in Visual Studio; I selected one of the controls bound to a property of the "Criteria" object and then walked up the visual tree whilst keeping an eye on the "DataContext" property of each ancestor control until it matched with the object type (class) that I was expecting.